# How to access nested Hashmap

Tags: java, android, dictionary, hashmap, android-geofence

I want to access the Inner Hashmap so I can great a geofence, where each geofence has a custom radius.

I have looked all over the internet for a answer to this problem, but I dont seem to find any bit of code that looks similar and the other posted about how to access a nested Hashmap dont help my problem.

Please any help or advice will be appreciated.

I have tried everything from what I have read up on related posts but nothing seems to work.

```
private void setmGeofenceList(HashMap<String, Map.Entry<LatLng,Integer>> mhashMap)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<LatLng,Integer>> entry : mhashMap.entrySet()) {

            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setLoiteringDelay(1000)
                    .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
                    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                    // geofence.
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                    // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                    .setCircularRegion(

                            //THIS is the problem, this wont access the LatLng Value that is inside the inner hashmap
                            entry.getValue().latitude, //error: cant access sysmbol Latitude

                            entry.getValue().longitude, //error: cant access sysmbol Longitude


                    )
                    // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                    // removed after this period of time.
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)

                    // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                    // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                    // Create the geofence.
                    .build());

        }
    }
```

// this is where the Hashmap stores the Values

```
    static final HashMap<String, Map.Entry<LatLng,Integer>>RED_LINE_GEOFENCES = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("PlatformA", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.905679, 19.112890), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("Ticket Office", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.911024, 19.119688), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("Maison", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.886851, 19.076072), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("Mont Rochelle", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.914458, 19.106716), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("Holden Manz", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.934360, 19.113939), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("Charmonix", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.899535, 19.127489), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("DieuDonne", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.891131, 19.133831), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("Grande Provance", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.899443, 19.103134), 300));
        RED_LINE_GEOFENCES.put("Rickety Bridge", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new LatLng(-33.894788, 19.097545), 300));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entry.getValue()` returns a map entry of which LatLng is the key. So to access them you need `entry.getValue().getKey().latitude` and `entry.getValue().getKey().longitude`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing getKey() call. You need this;

```
 entry.getValue().getKey().latitude
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
entry.getValue().latitude, //error: cant access symbol Latitude
entry.getValue().longitude, //error: cant access symbol Longitude
```

use these statements:

```
entry.getValue().get("latitude");
entry.getValue().get("longitude");
```